# sass interpolation error using "(not"

Tags: sass

I'm trying to do this:

```
$grid-query-xlarge: "(not print) and (min-width: #{$screen-xlarge})" !default;
```

and then this

```
@media #{$grid-query-xlarge}  {
```

The `(not` is causing problems. It says

> error scss/columndrop.scss (Line 25: Invalid CSS after "(": expected
>   expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "not print) and ...")

If I change `not` to `nop` it passes it through, though needless to say that doesn't actually work. Seems like sass trying to interpret the not. Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Format your code and give us full example that we can just copy-paste to some online converter, not just a part. It's not difficult but you are not alone

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you're attempting to generate is invalid.  You will find that there are many instances where Sass chokes on invalid CSS, but the error it gives won't necessarily reflect that since the parser is expecting it to be valid for other reasons.

Invalid:

```
@media (not print) {
    ...
}
```

Valid:

```
@media not print {
    ...
}
```

Comment: oh, I see, I didn't read this properly, I was copying what I thought was syntax... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#not